# Strange subset of C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X\subset C[0,1] $ denotes the set of functions $f \in C[0,1]$ such that

$f(\frac{1}{n})=2f(1-\frac{1}{n}), \ n=1,2,...$

Prove that $X$ is closed, infinitely dimensional vector subspace of $C[0,1]$.

So I know that to show that $X$ is closed I have to take any sequence $f_k \in X$ and prove that the limit of that sequence belongs to $X$. But it seems to me very absract and I need your help

Comment: Is not easier in this case to show that its complement is open?

Comment: It is not that abstract. You have to take a **convergent** sequence. So take $f_k \in X$ such that $f_k \to f$ in $C([0,1])$ and show that $f_k \in f$. It means show that for any $n$, $f(1/n) = 2f(1-1/n)$. But you already know that $f_k(1/n) = 2f_k(1-1/n)$ and that $f$ converges to $f_k$, so....

Comment: @justt Good idea, but that comment has a few hiccups. Surely you mean "... and show that $f\in X$" rather than $f_k\in f$. Also, $f$ doesn't converge to $f_k$, but the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show that it is infinite dimensional note that we have the constraint $f(1/2)=0.$ Now, consider any $h\in C[0,1/2]$ such that $h(1/2)=0.$ Then define

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}h(x), &0\le x\le \dfrac12, \\ \dfrac 12 h(1-x), & \dfrac 12 <x\le 1 \end{cases}$$ Since all these functions belong to $X$ it must be easy to get that it is infinite dimensional.

Now, consider $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $f\not\in X.$ So, there exists $n\in\Bbb{N}, n\ge 2$ such that $|f(\frac{1}{n})-2f(1-\frac{1}{n})|=\epsilon>0$ or $|f(1/2)|=\epsilon>0.$ Thus, $B(f,\epsilon/2)\cap X=\emptyset,$ which shows that $X$ is closed.

Comment: @user251257 Sure. Thank you for noticing the typo.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear to me why it is closed. But I still don't see why it is infinitely dimensional subspace

Comment: @Z.Princc Consider $h(x)=(x-1/2)x^n.$ The factor $x-1/2$ is to have $h(1/2)=0.$ Note we have infinitely many polinomyals of different degree in such a set.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Youre the best. Thanks to you I can learn a lot!

Comment: @Z.Princc You're welcome.